# Colorbox onload works, but overpowers other colorbox calls

Tags: jquery, colorbox, onload

I'm trying to get colorbox to load inline HTML (inline_content_1) when the page loads. I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"440px"});
   $(".inline").colorbox({href:"#inline_content_1", open:true, width:"330px", height:"640px"});
});
```

However, I also have 4 other inline colorbox calls on the page which do not need to work onload:

```
<div id='inline_content-2'>...html...</div>
<div id='inline_content-3'>...html...</div>
<div id='inline_content-4'>...html...</div>
<div id='inline_content-5'>...html...</div>
```

The correct inline HTML (inline_content_1) pops up onLoad, but then every colorbox link on the page (inline_content_2,3,4,5) loads 'inline_content_1'.

Please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are telling all the elements with a class of 'inline' that you want with the selector '#inline_content-1'.

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"440px"});
   $.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content_1", open:true, width:"330px", height:"640px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to use the id of the div you want to come up at `onload`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inline #inline_content-1").colorbox({inline:true, width:"440px"});
    $(".inline #inline_content-1").colorbox({href:"#inline_content_1", open:true, width:"330px", height:"640px"});
});
```

Thank you for taking time to think about this!
I am currently using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"440px"});
        $(".inline #inline_content_onload").colorbox({href:"#inline_content_onload", open:true, width:"330px", height:"640px"});
    });
</script>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content-1'> HTML here</div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content-2'> HTML here</div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content-3'> HTML here</div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content-4'> HTML here</div>
</div>

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content_onload'> HTML onload here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that and resulted in an empty colorbox to open onload, which then locked itself up (empty box, spinner icon, page froze)

Comment: Colorbox loads content from the href you pass it, right? And then populates the element you used it on?

Comment: Could you post your full html?

Comment: @user1472516 Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/hSxcr/3/